# No direct script access allowed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I used following line in one of my php file but it shows the error like

> Error : 'No direct script access allowed'

and the line is 
`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application/config/database.php');`. 
How to solve this?

Comment: You should not call database.php file directly, you should load database `$this->load->database();` like this

Answer (score 1):

You should not call database.php file you should load database

```
$this->load->database();
```

or go to `constants.php` and define the the path of the file

then add it using `BASEPATH`